# how can I install unpublished package from source code

Tags: r, shiny, r-package, shinyapps

A colleague of mine has just built a shiny app for 16s rRNA amplicon. for that he has built a helper package for shiny app which contains all other packages needed for the app to work for example: dada2, dplyr, plyr, DECIPHER, phangorn etc etc. He has installed it in R but now I have to change some code in that helper package to add some of the new features in the app but I can’t find a way to install that package after modifications This package does not have any tar.gz or any zip file only a folder containing R scripts.

NOTE: I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Can you open it as a project in RStudio?

Comment: yes i have opened the .rproj file and it is openeing the source code file and otheer files like: .gitignore, DESCRIPTION, NAMESPACE, README.md and Analysis(file with source code)

Comment: Then you should see the *Build*  panel in RStudio, which has menu items for building a package. Btw., I strongly recommend you use git for version control.

Comment: yes i have found that panel but the problem is it is only showing up on that particular computer on which that package and app was built but i am trying it onto another laptop by copying all the files and opening that .rproj file but it is not opening on the other laptop (because i want to edit it onto laptop so that i may not make things more worsen)

Comment: Please see `?install.packages` pkgs: `character vector of the names of packages whose current versions should be downloaded from the repositories.

If repos = NULL, a character vector of file paths,
[...]
On Unix-alikes,
these file paths can be source directories or archives or binary package archive files (as created by R CMD build --binary). (http:// and file:// URLs are also accepted and the files will be downloaded and installed from local copies.) On a CRAN build of R for macOS these can be ‘.tgz’ files containing binary package archives. Tilde-expansion will be done on file paths.`

Comment: it was a success thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. `remotes::install_local(path = "src")` to install the R package with its source code stored in directory `src`.